# CQ5: Sling request with two language code

Tags: internationalization, aem

I am currently working with a CQ5 application which has the below url of a node `..content/en_us/abc/xyz/bi/abc.html`.

The url contains the required language code 'en_us'. As per ISO language code list, 'bi' is listed as a language code. Sling is taking 'bi' as the language for the page and fails to get the translation from i18n.

In current business scenario we cannot change 'bi' to anything else.

Is there any way to get the translation from i18n using the correct language code i.e 'en_us' ?

Answer (score 0):

Set `jcr:language` on `en_us` node. You can do this using page property dialog or manually from crx/de. Open the dialog, go to the "Advanced" tab and set the language.